# Problem with /home

Tags: partitioning, home-directory

*Sry for my english.*
I had /home on the other partition. I delete this partition and in graphical mode i can't log in. In console i can. I have Ubuntu 15 with link to this partition and Lubuntu 15. In this and this I can't log in. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've trashed all your personal data, including settings for your GUI login. If you can get the `/home` partition back (using [TestDisk,](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) for instance, do so. If not, you may be able to recover by logging in to text mode and doing this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /home/{yourusername}
```

...where `{yourusername}` is your username (or the directory where your account's home directory existed).

If you do this and it works, you will have lost all your personal settings (desktop preferences, program settings, etc.), but you should at least be able to log in.